# Word Com Interop: Iterating all the ranges of a Word document in c#

Tags: c#, com-interop

I'm working on a .Net Framework 4.0 project using Com Interop and I have to iterate all the ranges with text from a Word document. I'm using the following code, based on [this](http://word.mvps.org/FAQs/Customization/ReplaceAnywhere.htm) and [this](https://www.wwco.com/~wls/blog/2010/07/03/find-and-replace-in-word-using-c-net/) articles. While in most cases it works correctly, some issues appear when you have a group of shapes or a canvas with shapes inside a header or footer. In those cases, the shape if the foreach loop is the group/canvas and I can't find access to the shapes inside them.

```
    private void IterateRanges()
    {
        foreach (Range range in _document.StoryRanges)
        {
            var currentRange = range;
            do
            {
                if (RangeStoryTypeIsHeaderOrFooter(currentRange) &&
                    CurrentRangeHaveShapeRanges(currentRange))
                {
                    foreach (Shape shape in currentRange.ShapeRange)
                    {
                        if (shape.TextFrame.HasText == 0)continue;

                        var finalRange = shape.TextFrame.TextRange;

                        DoSomething(finalRange);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    DoSomething(currentRange);
                }

                currentRange = currentRange.NextStoryRange;
            } while (currentRange != null);
        }
    }

    private bool RangeStoryTypeIsHeaderOrFooter(Range range)
    {
        return (range.StoryType == WdStoryType.wdEvenPagesHeaderStory ||
                range.StoryType == WdStoryType.wdPrimaryHeaderStory ||
                range.StoryType == WdStoryType.wdEvenPagesFooterStory ||
                range.StoryType == WdStoryType.wdPrimaryFooterStory ||
                range.StoryType == WdStoryType.wdFirstPageHeaderStory ||
                range.StoryType == WdStoryType.wdFirstPageFooterStory);
    }

    private bool CurrentRangeHaveShapeRanges(Range range)
    {
        return range.ShapeRange.Count > 0;
    }
```

I've tried to use the `CanvasItems` and `GroupItems` properties with no success. Their members do not have access to the `TextRange` property.

```
        foreach (dynamic groupShape in shape.GroupItems)
        {
            var textRange = groupShape.TextFrame.TextRange;
        }
```

Also, explicitly casting the `groupShape` to Shape throws an exception:

> Unable to cast COM object of type 'System.__ComObject' to interface
>   type 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Shape'.

Comment: I know this is old, but in general you should check the shape.Type property when working with non-inline shapes. It will tell you if it's a group, or a text box, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Delete all Bin and Obj folders. Include *Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.dll* file as reference in project for re-generation of interop related classes. Somewhere define **Shape** class as following for runtime to access it:

```
[GuidAttribute("000209A0-0000-0000-C000-000000000046")]
public interface Shape
```